# Prove a matrix is Hermitian, if its eigenvalues are real and satisfy an orthogonality relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove a matrix is Hermitian, if:

(a) Its eigenvalues are real, and
(b) the eigenvectors satisfy $ r_{i}^\dagger r_{j} = \delta_{ij} = \left<r_{i}|r_{j}\right> $

I can see this is the reverse of showing these are properties of an Hermitian matrix, but just can't see how to start this?

Comment: is the symbol after $r_{i}$ supposed to be representative of the complex conjugate?

Comment: It probably means $\langle r_i,r_j \rangle$.